# rad grid view update doesn't cause refresh

Tags: asp.net, view, grid

I used a rad grid view with sqldatasource (asp.net). I checked auto generate update and delete column and auto update and delete, but when I clicked on edit and changed a value then clicked on update link button nothing happened ... not even a refresh. However, the delete button works fine.

What should i do?

This is my code:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AllowAutomaticDeletes="True" AllowAutomaticUpdates="True" AutoGenerateDeleteColumn="True" AutoGenerateEditColumn="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" GroupPanelPosition="Top">
            <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="index" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                <Columns>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="index" DataType="System.Int32" FilterControlAltText="Filter index column" HeaderText="index" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="index" UniqueName="index">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="name" FilterControlAltText="Filter name column" HeaderText="name" SortExpression="name" UniqueName="name">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="price" DataType="System.Int32" FilterControlAltText="Filter price column" HeaderText="price" SortExpression="price" UniqueName="price">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="subject" FilterControlAltText="Filter subject column" HeaderText="subject" SortExpression="subject" UniqueName="subject">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="exp" FilterControlAltText="Filter exp column" HeaderText="exp" SortExpression="exp" UniqueName="exp">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="link" FilterControlAltText="Filter link column" HeaderText="link" SortExpression="link" UniqueName="link">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="img1" FilterControlAltText="Filter img1 column" HeaderText="img1" SortExpression="img1" UniqueName="img1">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="img2" FilterControlAltText="Filter img2 column" HeaderText="img2" SortExpression="img2" UniqueName="img2">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="img3" FilterControlAltText="Filter img3 column" HeaderText="img3" SortExpression="img3" UniqueName="img3">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="img4" FilterControlAltText="Filter img4 column" HeaderText="img4" SortExpression="img4" UniqueName="img4">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                </Columns>
            </MasterTableView>
        </telerik:RadGrid>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConStr %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [RPtbl] WHERE [index] = @index" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [RPtbl] ([name], [price], [subject], [exp], [link], [img1], [img2], [img3], [img4]) VALUES (@name, @price, @subject, @exp, @link, @img1, @img2, @img3, @img4)" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [RPtbl]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [RPtbl] SET [name] = @name, [price] = @price, [subject] = @subject, [exp] = @exp, [link] = @link, [img1] = @img1, [img2] = @img2, [img3] = @img3, [img4] = @img4 WHERE [index] = @index">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="index" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="price" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="subject" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="exp" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="link" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="img1" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="img2" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="img3" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="img4" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="price" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="subject" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="exp" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="link" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="img1" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="img2" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="img3" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="img4" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="index" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Primarily reformatting so that the code is readable.

Answer (score 2):

just call `Radgrid1.Rebind` event into the any one of the following methods in code- behind:

```
Private Sub RadGrid1_InsertCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs) Handles RadGrid1.InsertCommand
        RadGrid1.Rebind()
    End Sub
    Private Sub RadGrid1_ItemInserted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridInsertedEventArgs) Handles RadGrid1.ItemInserted
        RadGrid1.Rebind()
    End Sub
```

If you are using C#:

```
private void RadGrid1_InsertCommand(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    RadGrid1.Rebind();
}
private void RadGrid1_ItemInserted(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridInsertedEventArgs e)
{
    RadGrid1.Rebind();
}
```

Hope this helps...